# How to Join tables on CSV in one column that relates to multiple rows in another?

Tags: sql, csv, join

I am trying to figure out how to Join two tables together where the data structure looks like below.

So basically I need to look at the Product Level In TableA and if it is (x) then only include records where All of the ProductIdentifiers in Table A exist in the Type(x)ID of TableB

So looking at the "Data" below I would only expect to return Row 1 & 3 of Table a since all 3 Identifiers Exist in Table B in the correct Type(x)ID Column...

I hope that made sense because I am a little lost on how to achieve this.

Also FYI I am limited to fairly basic SQL, no sprocs or functions

TableA

```
-------------------------------------
ID | ProductIdentifier | ProductLevel
-------------------------------------
1  | 123, 234, 345     | 1
2  | 321, 432, 543     | 2
3  | 345, 544, 346     | 3
```

Table B

```
-------------------------------------
ID | Type1ID | Type2ID | Type3ID
-------------------------------------
1  | 123     | 321     | 345   
2  | 234     | 432     | 544  
3  | 345     | 233     | 346
```

Comment: Fix your data structure so you have a junction table.  Do not store lists of ids in a string.  Do not store integers as strings.  Do use foreign key references for columns that are designed to link two tables.

Comment: Any chance you can restructure Table B? You could change it to have 3 cols (ID, type, relatedID) and have 3 rows per Product in Table B. That way if you add more types then table structure doesn't have to change.

Comment: Sorry should have also said that I am stuck with this structure... Trust me the first thing I ask was could I change the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select * from TableA
inner join TableB on
'%,' + Type1ID + ',%' like ',' + ProductIdentifier + ',' AND
'%,' + Type2ID + ',%' like ',' + ProductIdentifier + ',' AND
'%,' + Type3ID + ',%' like ',' + ProductIdentifier + ','
```

may work who knows.  not great though.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should find a way to restructure the data (or at least have a separate table that aggregates the data into an easily queryable form).

However, query below should do the job.. although it is going to be pretty inefficient!! I'm assuming the data type of ProductIdentifier is a VARCHAR and can't be changed, therefore I have used replace and trim in the query to tidy it up.

Normalizing the data is the way to go on this... but if you really have to, try this:

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB as B1 on FIND_IN_SET(B1.Type1ID, trim(replace(ProductIdentifier,' ', ''))) > 0 
        and TableA.ProductLevel = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB as B2 on FIND_IN_SET(B2.Type2ID, trim(replace(ProductIdentifier,' ', ''))) > 0 
        and TableA.ProductLevel = 2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB as B3 on FIND_IN_SET(B3.Type3ID, trim(replace(ProductIdentifier,' ', ''))) > 0 
        and TableA.ProductLevel = 3
GROUP BY TableA.ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT B1.Type1ID) = 1+CHAR_LENGTH(ProductIdentifier)-CHAR_LENGTH(replace(ProductIdentifier,',', '')) /* Number of rows is equal to the number of items in ProductIdentifier (calculated using length of string minus length of string with commas removed) */
    OR COUNT(DISTINCT B2.Type2ID) = 1+CHAR_LENGTH(ProductIdentifier)-CHAR_LENGTH(replace(ProductIdentifier,',', ''))
    OR COUNT(DISTINCT B3.Type3ID) = 1+CHAR_LENGTH(ProductIdentifier)-CHAR_LENGTH(replace(ProductIdentifier,',', ''));
```